# Nginx Reverse Proxy & Rewrite with Parameters

Tags: nginx, parameters, proxy, reverse

I'm trying to deploy a Bokeh Server application that requires an input parameter ("Part") in the form:

```
(1) http://127.0.0.1:5100/myapp?Part=1234-567
```

I want to use rewrite so that when a user hits the below URL

```
(2) http://<my_hostname>/myappRenamed/Part=1234-567
```

Nginx reverse proxies to URL (1)

Right now, my config file is similar to below.

```
location /myappRenamed/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5100;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

This works when I hit

```
http://<my_hostname>/myappRenamed/myapp?Part=1234-567
```

Except I want the URL to be

```
http://<my_hostname>/myappRenamed/Part=1234-567
```

Comment: Here's a good related tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks Simon but this doesn't help me or answer the question.
I already have my server up and running properly. I'm actually already serving a couple flask applications as well as this Bokeh Server application. This specific case is mainly an issue of Nginx URL rewriting. I just want my URL to be user-friendly. Flask makes this easy to do within python. Unfortunately, Bokeh Server does not.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite the URL first, making it URL friendly using nginx rewrite capabilities and the proxy it:

```
location /myappRenamed/ {
    rewrite ^/myapp(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5100;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

I do not have your ENV so I can't really test the rule but you got the concept.

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't parse any parameters. It just reroutes to the main application page
    http://127.0.0.1:5100/myapp/